# play auto-test with SSL java key store troubles

Tags: java, playframework, openssl, keytool, jks

I am trying to set up Jenkins CI with the Play plugin, which uses play auto-test to run the app.

The problem is I've also got SSL as a requirement, but the firephoque java test browser doesn't have the proper key/cert to use.

I originally created a key/cert pair with OpenSSL, but now need to figure out how to import those keys into the global default Java Key Store (presumably in $HOME/.keystore).

I've tried these resources in varying order to no avail:

The original play google group thread that I started with: http://bit.ly/yZBezu

http://www.sslshopper.com/article-how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-using-java-keytool.html

http://www.agentbob.info/agentbob/79-AB.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/tooldocs/win32/keytool.html

I am able to run the app over SSL when the play runner picks up the keystore location from an entry in application.conf, but when auto-test runs the firephoque browser I get:

```
The application does not start. There are errors: 
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: 
    PKIX path building failed:
    sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:
        unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Would love to be pointed in the direction of a concise way to do this, my brain is fried with visions of DER and PEM and keytool fun right now I can't think straight.

End goal is a self-signed certificate that will validate under `play auto-test`, as well as any other ways of running the app.

My application.conf file has had varying combinations of the following:

```
# SSL - localhost default
# original way worked fine before auto-test came into play (so to speak :))
# certificate.key.file=conf/play_host.key
# certificate.file=conf/play_host.crt

# Keystore 
ssl.KeyManagerFactory.algorithm=SunX509
trustmanager.algorithm=JKS
keystore.password=passw0rd
keystore.file=conf/keystore.jks 
https.port=9443
```

**UPDATE**
The output of conf/keystore.jks:

```
# keytool -list -keystore keystore.jks
Enter keystore password:  

Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

localhost, Jan 31, 2012, PrivateKeyEntry, 
Certificate fingerprint (MD5): 36:EF:63:4E:53:23:18:22:13:8C:2C:DB:F1:72:2C:93
```

But this file is not accessed by the browser that runs inside the auto-test, it's firephoque, which is a java app that looks through the default keystore - did some more digging and started to look in

`/Library/Java/Home/lib/security/`

which symlinks to

`/System/Library/Java/Support/CoreDeploy.bundle/Contents/Home/lib/security`

to find a location where any app would be able to find a keystore. But I still get the same result if I put another keystore in the `security` folder above.

**UPDATE 2:** also tried

`play auto-test -Xmx1g -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/path/to/keystore.jks`

but I'm not sure I'm doing it right. How can I get the launch of play auto-test to look for the keystore in an explicit place?

Comment: not that it's really any help, but there is a ticket in their bugtracking system, which describes this problem. A fix for it exists, but is scheduled for 1.2.5 which isn't out yet: https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/57987/tickets/995

Comment: Thanks dertoni - in the end I patched my copy of play 1.2.4 with the new base.py file which allows auto-test to run even when SSL is configured. Works like a charm now.

Answer (score 2):

Not elegant but with play 1.2.5 on the horizon it's not a big deal to patch 1.2.4 to get this working.

https://github.com/playframework/play/commit/52f3c165cba1ea62e91a6c26ed62979b90da99c

Thanks to dertoni.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you followed the steps from the following link, your keystore should have the correct information.

http://www.sslshopper.com/article-how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-using-java-keytool.html

Do you know if your app is picking up the keystore ?
Can you specify the full path to the keystore file location (ie keystore.file=/home/some_user/conf/keystore.jks) ?
Also, can you send the output of the keystore ?

Comment: Yeah, I've been able to create keystores fine, I'm just not sure where to put the keystore so that firephoque can pick it up without having to explicitly set it. I'm on OSX Lion 10.7.2.

Comment: If firephoque is just a java process, you are on the right track. In addition to the truststore you will also need to specify the password "-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=blahblah". After it executes, can you check the executable command string (ps -ef | grep java) to ensure that it has taken all the variables ?

Comment: Hey Kevin - same issue when I have both java properties on the command line. In the end I patched my copy of play with a fix for base.py which was just not written with SSL in mind at all.